# Counting the number of 1's in an integer C

Tags: c, bit

What is the best way to count the number of 1's in an 32-bit integer x in C without using for or while loops, and without using constants greater than 0xFF?

What I thought of is shifting x 24 to the right and count how many 1's in the shifted integer and store that in a variable count. And then, shifting x 16 to the right and increment count by the number of 1's in the shifted integer, and so on.

So, any ideas of a better solution?

Comment: The code heavily relies on implementation defined behaviour, i.e. is not portable. It also can invoke undefined behaviour for too large shift counts on platforms with <25 bit `int`. Shifting signed integers is alwas problematic. Avoid it, unless you can guarantee the sign-bit is not involved (which means: just avoid it).

Comment: By number of ones do you mean the  binary representation of the number or the base 10

Comment: number of ones of the binary representation

Comment: @Mitchel0022: In a **binary** digital computer everything is encoded binary. And it is obviously not BCD.

Comment: It is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: @Olaf In a binary digital computer sometimes you want to count the number of ones that would appear in other bases as well

Comment: @kamarkiewicz: but I cannot use constants greater than 0xff

Comment: As just for/while loops are mentioned: is recursion an option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Comment: @StephanLechner: No, I am just allowed to use those operators (! ˜ & ˆ | + << >>)

Comment: So pretty much every operator, a few more than needed.

Comment: This requirement, with it's unreasonable constraints, is of negative use to future SO users/visitors.

Comment: you may want to take a look at Warren's book "Hacker's Delight", it has a chapter on counting bits.

Comment: @Mitchel0022: In a real world application? Most unlikely. And the code shown _obviously_ does not.

Comment: "I am just allowed to use those operators" - You are aware you have to state it is a homework dump, are you? Read [ask] and the linked posts.

Comment: What is "better"? Speed? Size? Power consumtion? Distribution of 0/1 bits in the machine code?

Comment: @HammamA I smell that this is your data lab homework.

Answer (score 1):

You can tabulate the number of 1's in all `d` bits numbers. This takes a table of `2^d` entries, each not exceeding the value `d` (`<255`).

Now you can cut your number in slices of `d` bits and lookup the counts for all slices.

A good compromise between space/number of operations is probably with `d=4` (`8` slices, table size=`16`).

Comment: That is not necessarily better, but worse.

Comment: @Olaf: what are you talking about ?

Comment: Most likely about what you wrote I'd say.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Don't worry about Olaf. I agree with you about your "good compromise" -- that's the technique I prefer, too.